# next-auth linkedin authentication giving error: OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 403 Forbidden

Tags: next.js, linkedin-api, next-auth

I have an application in which i am implementing linkedin auth using next-auth specifically next js 13 with app router. It goes to the consent screen but then after the callback from there in the terminal it throws the following error and user is not properly authenticated. I have checked the scope and the other params and they are passed correctly. Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error expected 200 OK, got: 403 Forbidden {
  error: OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 403 Forbidden
```

I tried almost everything from customizing the authoptions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As of August 1, 2023 LinkedIn [switched new Sign In with LinkedIn implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin) to use [OpenID Connect (OIDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2).

This meant that the default next-auth LinkedIn provider options no longer worked.

An example of a working set of options is at [this comment](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/8316#issuecomment-1690337350):

```js
LinkedInProvider({
      clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: { scope: 'openid profile email' },
      },
      issuer: 'https://www.linkedin.com',
      jwks_endpoint: 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/openid/jwks',
      profile(profile, tokens) {
        const defaultImage =
          'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png';
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture ?? defaultImage,
        };
      },
   })
```

I believe this is soon going to be merged in, so soon just upgrading to latest should fix this.